# Is it possible to build a headless Node-based client from Meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm working on a system where a remote machine (hooked up to a projector and some other hardware) is controlled via a Meteor application. Currently, we are using a home-grown DDP client written in C++ to accomplish this, but this approach is not as flexible as I would like:

- There is duplication between C++ and JavaScript.
- Upgrades are hard because we can't deploy both the server and the client at the same time, so we always have to think about backwards compatibility and ordering.

So I'm toying with the idea of rewriting the Meteor part of the C++ app in JavaScript. What I would like, ideally, is to have a special client of our app (call it `headless`, akin to to `server` and `client`) which:

- is built from the same source as the rest of the Meteor app, so we can reuse the same business logic as on the server and web client,
- runs in Node.js on the client machine so it can access the OS, and
- doesn't contain any of the browser code, but adds some other code specific to controlling the machine and communicating with the C++ app.

Even better would be if this client would not contain any of the actual code, but just a piece of bootstrap code. The bootstrapper would download the actual application code from the server and re-download it when the server is updated, in the same way as happens for the HTML client. That would make updates much easier, because we can assume that server and client are always running the same version.

Does such a thing exist? If not, how close can I get without unreasonable effort? Searches for "meteor headless client" and "meteor node client" are not helping me, and the [only somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400568/two-way-communication-between-meteor-and-node) I could find isn't well answered.

Comment: Well, it won't be trivial. You will likely need to somehow add a new platform to the build (I don't think that it is documented anywhere and will probably involve forking Meteor)  or build your bundle when Meteor is built. I am not sure what exactly you plan on including, but building it separately and hinting your node client when there is a new bundle to download might be a more reasonable way of doing it. Then, you may be able to even extract the bundle and load the code at runtime or restart node with the new source.

Comment: Have you considered using `DDP.connect` to connect two meteor servers? Except for bootstrapping, I think it would solve your problem. In a way `DDP.connect` is exactly what you would use to make another server connect to another server just a client would. If you build it right, the code base for the two servers can actually be identical -- a Meteor.settings value could indicate master vs. slave.

Comment: I like the idea of a new platform, even though that might fall in the "unreasonable effort" category... As for code bundle update, this sounds really like what Meteor provides for Cordova clients. In the end, it seems to me that such a use case hits the need for more modularity / flexibility in Meteor (like the ability to specify a new platform).

Comment: Pushing further the analogy with a Cordova client, the specific code to communicate with your C++ part would then have been like a Cordova plugin: an independent module that exposes "native" functionalities to the business logic.

Comment: This sounds interesting. Does the client have to be in c++, or can it be done in javascript? Or can the hardware interface be done in c++, providing an api to a meteor server? The two meteor servers can communicate using DDP. Could you refactor the code to put most of the smarts in the main meteor server, and have the hardware controller just focus on controlling the hardware (reducing the need for it to be updated?)

Comment: @ChristianFritz Interesting idea, I hadn't considered that. But wouldn't the "client server" also need a MongoDB instance of its own? There will eventually be many of these, and synchronizing the entire database onto each is a security issue, as these machines are not as trusted as our server.

Comment: @Mikkel The hardware interface has to be C++, I was hoping to build the Meteor/DDP bits in JS. A client that's as "thin" as possible is definitely a good idea, and indeed is what we're moving towards (exactly because the C++ DDP client is a maintenance burden).

Comment: I don't think you have to have a mongo db for each server - you can define MONGO_URL to be something that is shared between them

Comment: @Mikkel It would still need access to the actual MongoDB server, hence still a security issue.

Comment: If the clients don't really need access to the main database, you could have a simple database just containing whatever common configuration information, and then security wouldn't be an issue

Comment: @thomas yes, each client-server (let's call it slave) uses mongodb, but what you subscribe to from the master is your choice. You don't need to synchronize the entire master db, only what you need on this specific slave (just like on a web client).

Comment: Here's another way which is in line with your way of thinking about a hot code push. You put the javascript code in the mongodb, and the meteor server on the client machine's job is to unpack new versions and start the nodejs server. If it doesn't fire up, it can revert to a previous version, much like meteor does with Cordova apps

Comment: Did you try phantom js?

Comment: @PankajJatav No. Could you be more specific?

Comment: As per my understanding, you want something like handless browsers. So I suggest you look into the phantom.js:http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html

Comment: You can also look for Casper js as well:https://www.npmjs.com/package/casperjs

Comment: You can read more about phantom and Casper here: https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get this to work by using the [meteor-desktop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-desktop) package to build your remote headless client.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-desktop#architecture

> In Electron app, there are two processes running along in your app.
>   The so-called main process and renderer process. Main process is just
>   a JS code executed in node, and the renderer is a Chromium process. In
>   this integration your Meteor app is being run in the renderer process
>   and your desktop specific code runs in the main process. They are
>   communicating through IPC events. Basically, the desktop side
>   publishes its API as an IPC event listeners. In your Meteor code,
>   calling it is as simple as Desktop.send('module', 'event');.

This will give you:

- os access on this (desktop) client
- [hot code push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-desktop#hot-code-push-support) (with caveats around the node modules)
- provides [Meteor.isDesktop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-desktop#meteorisdesktop) to control which code runs on the browser vs the desktop client

Comment: That looks very promising! I might need to remove/disable the Electron bits, but maybe we can actually put Electron to good use (there's a projector attached to the machines too, after all). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the Meteor client as a headless client, and since client runs in the browser, I'd suggest your look at using a headless browser like **PhantomJS**, which can run your Meteor code without the UI, and has the ability to access the local file system.

Another option, which is not really what you describe but would make everything javascript, is to use the node `ddp` client, and write your code in modules you can easily import on the node side.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a regular meteor client on the remote machine with custom hardware?  Or is that the C++ program acting as a client? And then a server, in addition to your other client browser?

Sounds like you should actually do a few things differently:

- Set up a dynamic DNS system with a custom domain and port forwarding so you can use the special hardware remote system as a server.
- Run the Meteor server on that remote machine with hardware.
- Instead of a full C++ app speaking DDP, just make a Node.js C++ addon that talks to the hardware and use that in the Meteor server code.

Comment: The C++ program acts as a client, using a DDP client that I wrote (there wasn't a good one out there -- need to talk to people about open-sourcing it!). But you seem to be misunderstanding -- the remote system is the client, not the server. There will be more than one of them, and they're not fully trusted.